# How can I create a int field in OnGui in editorwindow script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
private void OnGUI()
    {
        if(GUILayout.Button("Test"))
        {
           testTarget = EditorGUILayout.IntField("Testing : ", TestTarget());
        }
    }
```

I see only the button but not the int field inside.

testTarget is a static int variable and TestTarget is just a simple method that returns an int number.

Comment: Try to execute first the method in up line and asign to a var, and use this var instead of the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite understand what you are trying to achieve .. if you put the int field within the button if case ... well then it will be drawn only exactly in the one frame where you click the button ... you most probably want the int field drawn always so either before or after the button draw.

What I guess you want to do is something like

```
private int? tempTestTarget;

private void OnGUI()
{
    // Draw the intfield above the button
    // store the value in a temporary field
    // Maybe only the first time get the value from the method
    tempTestTarget = EditorGUILayout.IntField("Testing : ", tempTestTarget.HasValue ? tempTestTarget.Value : TestTarget());

    if(GUILayout.Button("Test"))
    {
       // only on click assign the value to the actual target field
       testTarget = tempTestTarget.Value;
    }
}
```